# Need to merge multiple tables from sql

Tags: mysql-workbench, sql-query-store

I have multiple tables in DB for a different date for the entire month.
I need to merge all the tables in a single file.

File names will be like

Dc_comment_20181101
Dc_comment_20181102
Dc_comment_20181103
Dc_comment_20181104
Dc_comment_20181105
Dc_comment_20181106
Dc_comment_20181107
Dc_comment_20181108

I need to unite all the files, all the files have same column name. My requirement is needed to unite all file. Where file date is different, is there any option to fix the file name as fixed, date as "*"

SELECT column_name(s) FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table2;

Instead of typing all the file name, can we fix the file name like "Dc_comment_201811**" in a single query to merge all the table?

Can anyone help on this

Answer (score 0):

A JOIN clause is used to combine rows from two or more tables, based on a related column 
  between them.
  Let's look at a selection from the "Orders" table:

SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderDate
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID;

Comment: Thanks for the comments Mahesh, following are the individual files Dc_comment_20181101 Dc_comment_20181102 Dc_comment_20181103 Dc_comment_20181104 Dc_comment_20181105 Dc_comment_20181106 Dc_comment_20181107 Dc_comment_20181108

Comment: in select option I have to type all the file name for merging, using "union" clause, In file name only the date will differs, rest everything will same